# Letters f overlapping if used after each other in CMU Serif

Tags: fonts

When I use CMU Serif, letter "f" overlaps with other letters "f" when one follows another. Here is what it looks like:

[image: ff_overlap]

What do I do to fix it? I don't think that the problem is with my PC. I tried it on different machines. Even Overleaf has the same problem with CMU Serif.

Comment: That's a ligature.  It's on purpose.  In the unlikely case that you want to suppress it use `dif{}ferent`.

Comment: Bruno's comment is correct. It does not only apply to that font. Many other fonts have this ligature. There are also several methods for globally disabling such ligatures, but the one to use might depend on how you compile (and might not be what you really want).

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch, thanks for solution. Could you please tell me if there is a way to suppress it outside TeX environment?

Comment: @RobtAll, that is correct. Could you please suggest a way to suppress it outside TeX environment?

Comment: Most modern applications and operating systems use ligatures by default. If you don't like the way they look in CMU Serif, your best option is to use a different font. Suppressing them in non-TeX applications is off-topic here, but it might be possible to adjust settings in specific applications.

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch, could you please write an answer with `dif{}ferent`, so I can mark it as solved?

Comment: To be fair, this particular ligature does look a little off, almost like it's been faked with kerning except for the stretch to the top of the first f

Comment: @Chris H, I happen to have numerous plots now that have "potential di**ff**erence" on one of the axes. The **ff** looks quite ugly, so I didn't even think that it is normal.

Comment: Bruno's original suggestion `dif{}ferent` is the most reliable way to do it, regardless of TeX packages or compiler. Outisde of TeX, such as in a word processor, there is probably a program setting `turn off ligatures` or something like that.